# Passing arguments in Pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to calculate pi with a recursive, concurrent program. the program calculates pi with different degrees of precision.

I have one code that works and one that doesn't. The only parts that differ between the two is how the arguments are passed when the threads are created. Both versions create *np* threads and pass them into a recursive function. The argument that they pass is a struct:

```
struct args{double l, r, fl, fr, area; long id;};
```

and they pass it to the function parallel_quad:

```
void *parallel_quad(void *myargs) {

    struct args *args = myargs;

    /* passing the arguments to local variables */
    double l = args->l;
    double r = args->r;
    double fl = args->fl;
    double fr = args->fr;
    double area = args->area;

    /* calculating the new parameters using the 
       adaptive quadrature routine formulas */
    double m = (l+r)/2;
    double fm = f(m);
    double larea = (fl+fm)*(m-l)/2;
    double rarea = (fm+fr)*(r-m)/2;
    /* if the result is not within the given error estimate,
       continue the recursion  */   
    if (fabs((larea + rarea) - area) > epsilon) {
        args->l = l;
        args->r = m;
        args->fl = fl;
        args->fr = fm;
        args->area = larea;

        parallel_quad(args);

        args->l = m;
        args->r = r;
        args->fl = fm;
        args->fr = fr;
        args->area = rarea;

        parallel_quad(args);

    } else {
        result[args->id] += larea + rarea;
    }
}
```

The one that works (it returns pi = 3.14159265354728356456) uses an array for the arguments. It looks like this

```
struct args args[np];

for (i = 0; i < np; i++){
    args[i].id = i;
    args[i].l = i * dxPerThread;
    args[i].r = args[i].l + dxPerThread;
    args[i].fl = f(args[i].l);
    args[i].fr = f(args[i].r);
    args[i].area = (f(args[i].l)+f(args[i].r))*(args[i].r-args[i].l)/2;
    pthread_create(&workerid[i], NULL, parallel_quad, &args[i]);    
}
```

while the version that doesn't work (it returns pi = 3.26262338311626587384) look like this

```
for (i = 0; i < np; i++){
    id = i;
    l = i * dxPerThread;
    r = l + dxPerThread;
    fl = f(l);
    fr = f(r);
    area = (f(l)+f(r))*(r-l)/2;
    struct args *myargs = malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    myargs->l = l;
    myargs->r = r;
    myargs->fl = fl;
    myargs->fr = fr;
    myargs->area = area;
    myargs->id = id;
    pthread_create(&workerid[i], NULL, parallel_quad, (void*)myargs);   
}
```

and another version, that returns pi = 0.12103072956898178192, looks like this

```
for (i = 0; i < np; i++){
    id = i;
    l = i * dxPerThread;
    r = l + dxPerThread;
    fl = f(l);
    fr = f(r);
    area = (f(l)+f(r))*(r-l)/2;
    struct args *myargs = malloc(sizeof(struct args));
    myargs->l = l;
    myargs->r = r;
    myargs->fl = fl;
    myargs->fr = fr;
    myargs->area = area;
    myargs->id = id;
    pthread_create(&workerid[i], NULL, parallel_quad, &myargs); 
}
```

and, as it happens,  3.26262338311626587384 -  0.12103072956898178192 = 3.14159265354728356456. I'm pretty new to C, pointers and structs and I don't really understand what's happening here. It seems the version that works passes a pointer to the adress of the struct that holds the arguments (struct args *), while the other passes a void-pointer (void *). So in other words, the one that works passes an adress on the stack and the one that doesn't work passes a pointer to the heap. What's the difference? Why doesn't both return the same value?

Comment: Not a [mcve], you must include all necessary code to compile. Or at least a function that compile.

Comment: Is myargs in the 2nd and 3rd pieces of code the same type as args in the 1st piece of code.  In your 3rd  piece of code, you should be passing (void*)myargs instead of &myargs.  Note that it is very confusing to name the structure and the variables (args) the same.

Comment: Check the types of all variables.

Comment: Did you check which parameters end up in your thread? The resulting values for pi are not very useful for us as we do not know your implementation.

Comment: Coincidental to the issue of 'variant results', but the second two examples both leak memory because you allocate with `malloc()` but don't keep a record of the allocation (unless the thread function releases its memory, which would be feasible but unusual, and the code wouldn't work for the first example where you don't use `malloc()`).

Comment: You don't show the `struct args` structure, or how/where you define the `args` array in the working code.  The memory returned by `malloc()` is not zeroed; maybe you aren't setting all the elements, but the working code has zeros because the `args` array is file scope or static and hence is initialized to all zeros.  Does using `calloc()` alter anything?  The third example breaks because you should pass `myargs` (like in the second).  It is surprising that this produces stable answers, though.  You don't show the variable declarations; could you have mixed up types?  You don't show `f()`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. Perhaps we can get rid of the third version, since the pointer-to-pointer is obviously wrong. Then, let's make the first and second versions more similar, e.g. by a line like `struct args *myargs = &args[i];` Isolating the stack vs. heap difference should help determine whether it's having an effect.